# how to add a mlab database to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb and connected to it using my terminal. Everything is fine, but the db is the test one. I created an account in mlab to add a new database, but I don't understand how to do so. I have already created a db user.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. Migrate mLab database to your local computer? Or connect to mLab db with your terminal?

Comment: I want to use mlab's database with mongodb in order to create a python app.

Comment: Mlab is a MongoDB service hosted on the cloud, what do you mean you want to "use" Mlab with MongoDB? do you just want to use the service? or get it onto your local MongoDB?